# Google sign in and authentication

Tags: android, authentication, google-api

I am working on an android app and want to authenticate the user via Google sign in.

Is there a way where i don't have to use any server, rather just add list of Gmail accounts somewhere on Google's developers account and only those users will be able to use my app, whose accounts are in my list.

is this how fire base works?

Answer (score 0):

You'll always need a server to authenticate the users with. If you want to restrict your app to certain users, maybe try closed alpha/beta testing?